# Payara/EclipseLink: count on collection which owner is an Embedable return 0

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, payara

Currently, I am trying to update the [eclipse-ee4j/cargotracker](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/cargotracker) to the latest Jakarta EE 8:

https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker/tree/jakartaee8

There is a **Cargo** entity that has an **Itinerary** embeddable property that has a list of **Leg**(Entity).

Dummy code fragments of the relations:

```java
@Entity class Cargo{
    @Embedded itinerary;
}

@Embedable class Itinerary{
    @OneToMany List<Leg> legs
}
@Entity class Leg{}
```

When counting the legs of a Cargo, the following works on both WildFly and Payara, check the complete testing codes [here](https://github.com/hantsy/cargotracker/blob/jakartaee8/src/test/java/org/eclipse/cargotracker/infrastructure/persistence/jpa/CargoRepositoryTest.java#L307):

```java
 var count = cargoRepository.find(trackingId).getItinerary().getLegs().size();
```

But I tried to use JPQL or native query, neither worked on Payara/EclipseLink, both return 0, but they **worked well** on WildFly/Hibernate.

```java
this.entityManager.createQuery("select count(e) from Cargo c join c.itinerary.legs e where c.trackingId = :id").setParameter("id", trackingId).getSingleResult()

this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from Leg where cargo_id = ?1").setParameter(1, cargo_id).getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Native query is to the database using direct SQL - how could it have worked with one JPA provider but not another? Could it be due to test setup or pointing at a DB with no results?

Comment: @Chris The native query should be JDBC compatible, if I do not change the JDBC drivers, on the same DB, it should return the same result. You are right, the JPA providers maybe introduce different behaviors. Eg. the above native query, Hibernate supports named params, but EclipseLink dose not, it is reasonable. The name params is not a standard in JDBC, but the positional params is.

Comment: Before I commented out the code frag, I have tested them in a clean DB setup(via docker).

Comment: JPA provers must not touch SQL in a native query so differences in results is something else. Both JPA providers can log what they issue - turning on SQL logging would help here. First guess is you are issuing the query over a different EM/transactional scope to the one making the changes, and it hasn't committed - this would depend on the container/test case setup. Smaller oddities in your code like having orderBy on mappings with OrderColumn annotations but using different fields seem like you made some non-spec workarounds that should be cleaned up as they will behave differently

Comment: Does it work if you put the Legs List directly into Cargo?

Comment: `OrderColumn` ensures Hibernate persists the legs in the natural order that is consistent with the result of applying `OrderBy`. If it is not set, the order in DB and  in mem is different and more strange after it is persisted, and to get legs immediately, the order of list item is db order, not `OrderBy` result. When retrieving again by query, the `OrderBy` is applied.  EclipseLink does not have this problem.

Comment: I have not tried to put the Leg list into Cargo. Currently, I just tried to update the existing eclipse-ee4j/cargotracker. The Leg itself in concept should be a Value Object, but it seems JPA spec does NOT support an embedded property contain a List of embedable objects.